# Slideshow from an ArrayList of images with JavaFX

Tags: java, arraylist, javafx

I'm trying to create a slideshow by taking an `ArrayList` of images and putting them into an `ImageView` using a `for` loop. However, in order to "pause" the program so that each image will be visible, I am trying to use `Thread.sleep`. This unfortunately hasn't had the desired effect. In trying to remedy this, my endless googling leads me to suspect that I should be using the `Timeline` class, but I have no idea how to implement it. Any help would be much appreciated. My dysfunctional code as it stands looks like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < imageArrayList.size(); i++) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error: " + e.toString());
    }
    slideshowImageView.setImage(imageArrayList.get(i));
}
```

Comment: Do some research into concurrency in JafaFx, you need to setup some kind of timer which will trigger a callback method within the context of the GUI thread

Comment: I posted an answer below, please let me know if it helps/does not help

Answer (score 2):

Figured it after a good long while of googling

```
    int count; //declared as global variable         



//then the working logic in my eventhandler
    Task task = new Task<Void>() {
            @Override
            public Void call() throws Exception {
                 for (int i = 0; i < imageArrayList.size(); i++) {
                     Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                         @Override
                         public void run() {
                              slideshowImageView.setImage(imageArrayList.get(slideshowCount));
                              slideshowCount++;
                              if (slideshowCount >= imageArrayList.size()) {
                                  slideshowCount = 0;
                              }
                         }
                      });

                     Thread.sleep(1000);
                  }
                  return null;
            }
            };
            Thread th = new Thread(task);
            th.setDaemon(true);
            th.start();

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a `Timer` to update the image once per certain amount of milliseconds

```
public int count = 0;

// then in your method

long delay = 2000; //update once per 2 seconds.
new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        slideshowImageView.setImage(imageArrayList.get(count++));
        if (count >= imageArrayList.size() {
            count = 0;
        }
    }
}, 0, delay);
```

Also, `slideshowImageView` and `imageArrayList` must be either fields, or `final` variables, to be accessed inside the `TimerTask.

Comment: Nope, appreciate your speedy response but your code gave this error `code` Exception in thread "Timer-2" Exception in thread "Timer-10" Exception in thread "Timer-6" Exception in thread "Timer-0" Exception in thread "Timer-8" Exception in thread "Timer-5" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on FX application thread; currentThread = Timer-8 `code`

Comment: @agelston alright, what is the full stack trace? do you know what excactly is the issue? Pastebin me the full stack trace and I will fix my answer (also, could you please tell me, what is the line number of "new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {" line in your .java file?

Comment: Thanks man, you'll have to excuse my ignorance here. I may be tad out of my depth.... By Full Stack Trace do you mean something like this http://pastebin.com/bqpFDpE8 The new timer statement is on line 244

Comment: @agelston I think it is because the timer loop is going out side of the array's bounds. So at some point, it is trying to get an image from the list with an id that doesn't exist.

Comment: assignment is the package/class

Comment: @agelston You are getting `IllegalStateException` because you are calling a method that should be called on the fx application thread only. Post your `setImage` call to the fx thread using `Platform.runLater`